# The slope of a triangle's Euler line in terms of the slopes of its sides

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

Let $p$, $q$, $r$, be the slopes of sides of a triangle, and $m$ the slope of Euler line of the triangle. Then we may say

$$m= -\frac{3+pq+pr+qr}{p+q+r+3pqr}$$

provided that the denominator isn't zero. If it's zero the euler line of the triangle is parallel to $y$ axis.

I would like hints for proving this formula.

Comment: Look Lemma 1 in http://forumgeom.fau.edu/FG2013volume13/FG201318.pdf

Comment: Nice...but lemma 1 proof  in this 2013 paper seems sloppy. He made an restricted assumption/constraint that angles B and C are acute and $m_3>m_1>m_2$.

Comment: And besides that,  why $tan(HOS)=(m_1-m_E)/(1+m_1.mE)$ and not the same expression with opposite sign? We need a better demonstration, without unproven assumptions.

Comment: Some more food for thought: perhaps a better way to figure out Euler line slope is calculating the slope of radical axis of nine pont circle and circumscribed circle, because these lines are perpendicular to each other. In trilinear coordinates the equation of this radicalaxis is straightforward: $cosA.\alpha+cosB.\beta+cosC.\gamma=0$. Does anyone know how to extract a cartesian equation therefrom?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use vectors to prove this. Let $ABC$ be the triangle, $p,q,r$ slopes of $BC,AC,AB$, respectively. Note that $\overrightarrow{BC},\overrightarrow{CA},\overrightarrow{AB}$ are respectively parallel to $(1,p),(1,q),(1,r)$. By taking into account the triangle rule $\overrightarrow{AB}+\overrightarrow{BC}+\overrightarrow{CA}=\overrightarrow{0}$, we may assume:
\begin{align}
\overrightarrow{BC}= (q-r,p(q-r)),\\
\overrightarrow{CA}= (r-p,q(r-p)),\\
\overrightarrow{AB}= (p-q,r(p-q)).\\
\end{align}

Let $T$ be the centroid. We know that $\overrightarrow{AT}= \frac{1}{3}(\overrightarrow{AB}+\overrightarrow{AC})= \frac{1}{3}(2p-q-r,pq+pr-2qr)$.

Let $H$ be the orthocenter. $\overrightarrow{AH}$ is parallel to $\overrightarrow{n_{BC}}:(-p(q-r),q-r)$ and $\overrightarrow{BH}$ is parallel to $\overrightarrow{n_{AC}}:(-q(r-p),r-p)$, so we can write:
\begin{align}
\overrightarrow{AH}=\alpha(-p(q-r),q-r),\\
\overrightarrow{BH}=\beta(-q(r-p),r-p).
\end{align}
Since $\overrightarrow{AB}= \overrightarrow{AH}-\overrightarrow{BH}$, we have:
\begin{align}
-\alpha\ p(q-r)+\beta\ q(r-p) = p-q,\\
\alpha(q-r)-\beta(r-p) =r(p-q).
\end{align}
Multiply the second equation by $q$ and add it to the first one to get: $\alpha(q-p)(q-r)=(qr+1)(p-q)$, wherefrom $\alpha=-\frac{qr+1}{q-r}$. So:
$$\overrightarrow{AH}= -\frac{qr+1}{q-r}(-p(q-r),q-r)= (pqr+p, -1-qr).$$
Now $\overrightarrow{HT}= \overrightarrow{AT}- \overrightarrow{AH}=$
$$=\frac{1}{3}(2p-q-r,pq+pr-2qr)-\frac{1}{3}(3pqr+3p, -3-3qr)=
\frac{1}{3}(-p-q-r-3pqr,3+pq+qr+rp).$$
The slope of the Euler line is thus equal to:
$$-\frac{3+pq+qr+rp}{p+q+r+3pqr}.$$

Comment: Amazing! My congratulations. What a brilliant proof, showing the power of tackling the question using vectors!

Comment: By the way, two corollaries follow from the formula above proven:

Comment: 1. A triangle with sides having slopes p,q,r, is equilateral if and only if $3+pq+pr+qr=0$ and $p+q+r+3pqr=0$.

Comment: 2. the slope of radical axis of nine point circle and circumcircle of a triangle is $(p+q+r+3pqr)/(3+pq+pr+qr)$

Comment: @MrDudulex Yes, you are right.

Answer (score 0):

Let the slopes of the triangle's sides be $m_i:=\tan\theta_i$ (with $i=1,2,3$), and define $\sigma :=\theta_1+\theta_2+\theta_3$.

The Euler line passes through a triangle's circumcenter and centroid. If we inscribe the triangle in the origin-centered unit circle, the $y$-over-$x$ ratio of the centroid's coordinates give the line's slope. Specifically, a triangle with vertices 
$$P_i := (\;\sin(2\theta_i-\sigma), \cos(2\theta_i-\sigma)\;)$$ 
has centroid $\frac13(P_1+P_2+P_3)$, so that the slope of its Euler line is
$$\begin{align}
&\phantom{=\;-} \frac{\cos(\theta_1-\theta_2-\theta_3)+\cos(-\theta_1+\theta_2-\theta_3)+\cos(-\theta_1-\theta_2+\theta_3)}{\sin(\theta_1-\theta_2-\theta_3)+\sin(-\theta_1+\theta_2-\theta_3)+\sin(-\theta_1-\theta_2+\theta_3)}\\[6pt]
&= -\frac{3\ddot{\theta_1}\ddot{\theta_2}\ddot{\theta_3}+\ddot{\theta_1}\dot{\theta_2}\dot\theta_3+\dot\theta_1\ddot\theta_2\dot\theta_3+\dot\theta_1\dot\theta_2\ddot\theta_3}{3\dot\theta_1\dot\theta_2\dot\theta_3+\dot\theta_1\ddot\theta_2\ddot\theta_3+\ddot\theta_1\dot\theta_2\ddot\theta_3+\ddot\theta_1\ddot\theta_2\dot\theta_3} \quad\left(\;\dot\theta:=\sin\theta, \;\ddot\theta:=\cos\theta\;\right)\\[6pt]
&=-\frac{\ddot\theta_1\ddot\theta_2\ddot\theta_3\left(3+m_2m_3+m_3m_1+m_1m_2\right)}{\ddot\theta_1\ddot\theta_2\ddot\theta_3\left(3m_1m_2m_3+m_1+m_2+m_3\right)} \\[6pt]
&=-\frac{3+m_2m_3+m_3m_1+m_1m_2}{3m_1m_2m_3+m_1+m_2+m_3} 
\end{align}$$

Now, we need only note that the slope of $\overline{P_2P_3}$ is
$$\frac{\cos(-\theta_1+\theta_2-\theta_3)-\cos(-\theta_1-\theta_2+\theta_3)}{\sin(-\theta_1+\theta_2-\theta_3)-\sin(-\theta_1-\theta_2+\theta_3)} =\frac{2\sin(\theta_2-\theta_3)\sin\theta_1}{2\sin(\theta_2-\theta_3)\cos\theta_1} = m_1$$
Likewise, $\overline{P_3P_1}$ and $\overline{P_1P_2}$ have respective slopes $m_2$ and $m_3$. $\square$